# Поиск аномалий с помощью функции Anomalize

Tags: r

Задача состоит в том, что бы найти аномалии среди кол-ва проданных продуктов. 
Массив данных размером 5 х 1 832 966.

```r
           DMY       MCC  Art   Qp     Ql
1   2016-01-01 UA0000468 1801 3520    440
2   2016-01-01 UA0000468 3102 3024  604,8
3   2016-01-01 UA0000468 4419  270  521,1
4   2016-01-01 UA0000468 5537 1080 2084,4
5   2016-01-01 UA0000468 5538  540 1042,2
6   2016-01-01 UA0000468 5539 1080 2084,4
7   2016-01-01 UA0000468 5540  540 1042,2
8   2016-01-03 UA0010557 1802   44    5,5
9   2016-01-03 UA0010557 1901  176     22
10  2016-01-03 UA0010557 1902  286  35,75
11  2016-01-03 UA0010557 1903  198  24,75
12  2016-01-03 UA0010557 1904  220   27,5
13  2016-01-03 UA0010557 3101  162   32,4
...
```

```r
ASD <- read.csv(".../ASD.csv", sep=";")

library(tidyverse)
library(anomalize)
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
library(ggplot2)
library(forecast)
library(anytime)

trash1 <- ASD[, -2]
trash2 <- trash1[,-2]
trash3 <- trash2[,-2]
trash4 <- trash3[,-2]
trash5 <- trash4[,-2]
trash6 <- trash5[,-2]
trash7 <- trash6[,-4]
trash8 <- trash7[,-4]


trash8$DMY <- as.Date(trash8$DMY, format="%d.%m.%y")
#dput(head(trash8$DMY))
#is.data.frame(trash9$DMY)
#dput(head(trash8))


trash_tbl <- as_tibble(trash8)
trash_tbl 

trash_tbl %>%
  time_decompose(Qp, method = "stl") %>%
  anomalize(remainder, method = "iqr") %>%
  time_recompose() %>%
  plot_anomalies(time_recomposed = TRUE, ncol = 3 , alpha_dots = 0.5)
```

Это код, который я смог написать, но он выдаёт следующую ошибку:

```r
Error: Only year, quarter, month, week, and day periods are allowed for an index of class Date
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это исправить и правильно ли я вообще делаю это?

Comment: дата у вас неуникальна. на чём функций `time_decompose()` и спотыкается.